# Резервный канал и ipfw

Tags: маршрутизация, роутер, freebsd, ipfw

Есть FreeBSD шлюз и 3G-модем. Подружить их между собой не удалось. Тогда был предпринят следующий финт ушами. На сетевой карте шлюза, смотрящей в локалку, прописываем два адреса: 192.168.65.254/24 & 192.168.10.157/24. В локальной сети устанавливаем 3G-модем и 3proxy, добавляем второй ip 192.168.10.156. Убеждаемся, что при прямом соединении прокси работает. Поскольку бегать по всем машинам и включать/отключать прокси не хочется, то в ipfw пишем следующее правило:

```
fwd 192.168.10.156,8213 tcp from 192.168.65.0/24 to any dst-port 80
```

И, собственно, на этом затык. Пробовал, чтобы и прокси и пользователи были в одной сети - интернет есть, счетчик правил чего-то считает, но инет идет не через прокси, трафика на 3G-модеме нет. Резерв нужен на остаток месяца, чтобы остаться в пределах лимита трафика до конца года. То есть весь трафик заворачивать не обязательно, достаточно только www. На всякий случай приведу кусок конфига ipfw:

```
00050   24378   20855686 pipe 16 ip from not 192.168.65.0/24 to 192.168.65.1602500       0          0 deny ip from 192.168.65.250 to any via rl002900     754      48212 fwd 192.168.10.156,8213 tcp from 192.168.65.0/24 to any dst-port 8009990 1642133  721709596 divert 8668 ip from any to any via rl065535 2719182 1275563809 allow ip from any to any
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку ничего более умного в голову не пришло, то воспользовался просто "подставой" - шлюз перевел на соседний адрес .253, свой рабочий комп на .254. А все остальное уже дело техники.

Answer (score 0):

хотелось бы всё-таки побольше узнать о структуре сети (какой интерфейс с каким именем и куда смотрит), так же надо бы показать весь вывод ipfw list а не его кусок, ну и конечно же uname -a

К тому же проброс портов (а именно его вы как понимаю хотите сделать) в ipfw может и не сработать, что зависит от конфигурации ядра (тоже бы посмотреть)

Можете использовать rinetd: устанавливается из портов, конфигурация простейшая и работает стабильно (ток не забудьте прописать разрешения в ipfw)

Comment: Да поздно уже. Год закончился и проблема больше неактуальна.